# How to deal with an Incorrect XML Closing Tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Say I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<normalXMLNodeLevel1>
    <normalXMLNodeLevel2>
        <normalXMLNodeLevel3>
        </normalXMLNodeLevel3>
    </normalXMLNodeLevel>
<normalXMLNodeLevel1>
```

1. How would I go about reading the XML file so I still get the data, if even possible?
2. If there is a way to still read the XML data, how would you correct the issue programmatically using JavaScript?

Comment: use a RegExp to fix the closing tag name, which is trivial if `</normalXMLNodeLevel>` is not needed anywhere.

Comment: XML parsers have "draconian error handling". That means they stop when parsing errors occur. You will not be able to parse the document as XML. You could read the data in as text and parse it with your own algorithm.

Comment: that gives me the idea that you can parse it with the forgiving HTML parser instead; not sure how your tags will end up, but it should keep content and maybe you can clean it up from there...